# Finding Intersection and Converting Cumulative Sum Sequences into Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, algorithms

I'm interested in finding the smallest common point of intersection between two cumulative sum sequences created from arrays of numbers and exploring the possibility of converting these cumulative sum sequences into functions.

In Mathematica, I've made an attempt to create cumulative sum sequences as follows:

My Attempt in Mathematica:

(* Define two cumulative sum sequences as lists *)

- sequence1 = Accumulate[{2, 4, 5, 2}];
- sequence2 = Accumulate[{4, 5, 6, 2}];

(* Find the intersection of the sequences *)

- intersection = Intersection[sequence1, sequence2]

(* Output the intersection *)

- intersection

However, I encountered a limitation: the Accumulate function generates a list of values rather than a functional representation of the cumulative sum sequence. This limits my ability to efficiently find the smallest intersection point and work with multiple sequences.

I've explored using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I haven't been able to make it work effectively in this context.

I'm looking for a more general approach or algorithm to efficiently find the smallest intersection point between cumulative sum sequences and possibly convert these sequences into functions for easier manipulation. Any guidance or insights on solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.